# Youtube API Playlist Skip Function

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I saw this site http://youtube-related-music.appspot.com/index.html
You see what is the upcoming video and skip it if you want.

I need something like that but not related videos or search function.
Just middle region (video container,Now Playing, Next Button, Coming up next & Skip Button) works with youtube playlists.

Is it possible ? Which one is required? Player API or Data API ?

I'm noob at script writing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided shows a non-working page.

If you create and embed a playlist from youtube
You see now playing.
There´s a next button.
And you can see what was played and what will play next.

In addition there will be thumbnails for the whole list showing inside the player
your visitor can scroll troughh it and can go to any video directly.

No script needed...just embed a "playlist"
the code for that is shown on youtube´s playlist-pages.

Comment: At the time i read your post...there was just a search-field and it didn´t do anything, anyway my playlist suggestion should help you..or ?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply.

In [THIS](http://youtube-related-music.appspot.com/index.html) site you can search a video and play something.
Video comes with progress bar , thumbnail, video name, uploader, complated time, remaining time, coming up next and skip function.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCFYu.jpg

Skip function is different than "embed playlist".
Youtube's classic embed playlist only gives you next song button. But in this script, you can skip second song without first one finished ;).
But the problem is this script based on related videos.
It can be adapted for playlist?

Have a nice day

Thanks